# Button content does not change in real time

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a button. I want it to be a favorite toggle button inside a listbox. See code below:

```
<Page
    x:Class="W.Pages.ExPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Workout_EF.Pages"
    xmlns:converter="using:W.Converters"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:data="using:W.Model"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <converter:FavoriteValueConverter x:Key="favoriteConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListBox Name="MyListbox"
            SelectionMode="Single"                           
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind exs}"
            SelectionChanged="MyListbox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Ex">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Name="IsFavoriteToggle" Click="IsFavoriteToggle_Click">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <TextBlock
                                    x:Name="isFavoriteTextBlock" 
                                    Text="{x:Bind IsFavorite, Converter={StaticResource favoriteConverter}}"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            FontSize="16" 
                            Text="{Binding ExName}"
                            Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

My problem is when I hit this button it does not change the icon in it (from emtpy star to full star and vice versa) in real time.

If the listbox will be loaded again the correct icon is displayed.

The code behind is:

```
namespace W.Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class ExPage : Page
    {
        ObservableCollection<Exs> exs = new ObservableCollection<Exs>();        
        public ExPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Exs> tmpEx = e.Parameter as List<Exs>;
            foreach (Exs item in tmpEx)
            {
                exs.Add(item);
            }            
        }

        private void IsFavoriteToggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {              
            Button button = sender as Button;
            int index = MyListbox.Items.IndexOf(button.DataContext);            
            Ex ex = (Exs)MyListbox.Items[index];
            DAL.SetToFavorite(ex, !ex.IsFavorite);
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that there is some problem with the itemsource maybe. It needed to change its content after hitting the button. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common mistake that everyone make and that is `ObservableCollection<T>` is actually informing the binders about the changes in the collection not the objects in the collection.
You have a `IsFavorite` property in your `Esx` class that the button need to know about changes but for that, `Esx` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and if you need more help post the code for Esx class maybe we can help.

Answer (score 1):

As Emaud said, you have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your `Esx` class. And you also have to set set the `Mode` to `OneWay` in your binding because for `x:Bind` the default mode is `OneTime` so it does NOT listen to any changes.

```
Text="{x:Bind IsFavorite, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource favoriteConverter}}"
```